# Chrome not loading new styles after css update

Tags: google-chrome

Since the last week I'm running into a weird issue related to Chrome version 54.0.2840.71 on OSX. Somehow after updating the CSS the new styles are not loading after refreshing the page.

Styles are not loaded either after a hard refresh (CMD+Shift+R) of when browsing in incognito modus.

This doesn't happen in Firefox or Safari. Anyone else having the same issue or know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you checked that the source file was the updated one ? (as it worked well on FF or safari, it would be strange but, who knows).

Comment: Not really sure what you mean with the source file? It's just an edited and saved css file either local or on the FTP

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This may help. Open dev tools in browser then right click on refresh button of chrome. A menu will open. Select empty cache and hard reload.

[image]

If this is also not working then quit browser and try after relaunching.

Also look at chrome://appcache-internals/ for your page if there are some caches just delete those caches related to your page.

Comment: HOLY COW, I was having a crazy hard time with some css code using `:after` thinking it was not rendering properly with Chrome on a Mac and then I try this and BAM it works. You have no idea how much I thank you