# fonts awesome fa-stack issue with css not applying Chrome PC

Tags: css, glyphicons

I have some code that shows a notification of unread messages in the form of a font-awesome inbox with a red circle alert and the number of messages that are unread. The code works fine (so far tested) in firefox (mac and pc), ie and chrome PC.

This is the example I used http://codepen.io/johnstuif/pen/pvLgYp

Here is what it looks like on firefox (Mac)

[image]

It is not working on Chrome (Mac). I am able to see the inbox, but I am not able to see the red circle and number.

```css
.fa-stack 
{
    margin-bottom: -60px;
}
  
.fa-stack[data-count]:after
{
position:absolute;
right:66.9%;
top:-5%;
content: attr(data-count);
font-size:30%;
padding:.5em;
border-radius:999px;
line-height:.60em;
color: white;
background:rgba(255,0,0,.85);
text-align:center;
min-width:.1em;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="navbar-brand dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" id="inbox_container" style="margin-top: -9px">
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x" id="inbox_total" data-count="3">
    <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
</span>
</a>
```

I am assuming there is a bug issue with the browser but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to work with Chrome (mac) if I even can.

Comment: Please modify the snippet above so that it appears as it should (in the working browsers)

Comment: thats what I got so far, not sure why the red badge is off. It's weird I can see it here on stack but not on my site with a Mac running Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I discovered from some searching that all I had to do was do a [clearing of chrome cache and a hard reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383732/chrome-not-loading-new-styles-after-css-update) and it works now.

Amazing!